# Flow connector for document translation service?

Tags: microsoft-translator

Wondering if the document translation api in preview will have a flow connector coming soon to enable scenarios such as sharepoint documents, teams attachments etc?

Answer (score 0):

Document translation would have SDK as part of GA announcement.
We are gathering use case scenarios to prioritize on cross product integrations and connectors.

Comment: An sdk means a custom connector we would need to build in power automate which means a per user license to leverage the connector.   For a large enterprise it’s a million dollar ask.  If you provide a standard connector anyone can consume the service :-)